# What Is difference between angular 7 and 8?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

Actually, I want to know the actual differences of angular versions - 8 and 7 which were recently release the beta version.

I researched on the same but not able to understand the exact differences on these versions – angular 7 and 8.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: There is big talk about Ivy rendering, you may read about it here: https://blog.angular.io/a-plan-for-version-8-0-and-ivy-b3318dfc19f7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Angular 8 being smaller, faster and easier to use and it will make Angular developers life easier. Angular version numbers have three parts: major.minor.patch.

```
=> Added Support for TypeScript 3.2
=> Added a Navigation Type Available during Navigation in the Router
=> Added pathParamsOrQueryParamsChange mode for runGuardsAndResolvers in the Router
=> Allow passing state to routerLink Directives in the Router
=> Allow passing state to NavigationExtras in the Router
=> Restore whole object when navigating back to a page managed by Angular Router
=> Added support for SASS
=> Resolve generated Sass/Less files to .css inputs
```

The source from: *https://www.code-sample.com/2018/05/angular-8-vs-angular-7-vs-angular-6.html*

Comment: Here it is the official blog there is a helpful article about version 8 of Angular: https://blog.angular.io/version-8-of-angular-smaller-bundles-cli-apis-and-alignment-with-the-ecosystem-af0261112a27